# Trying to pass id variable from 'accounts' table to app.blade with undefined variable error

Tags: php, model-view-controller, view, laravel-5.4

I am trying to pass the id variable from the accounts table to the app.blade view to specify a custom URL for each user.  I am trying to store it in $account, but I am obviously not doing something right.

Error Message: Undefined variable: account (View: /home/vagrant/www/upsapp/resources/views/layouts/app.blade.php) (View: /home/vagrant/www/upsapp/resources/views/layouts/app.blade.php)

app.blade

```
<a class="navbar-brand" href=" {{ url('/account/'.$account->id).'/' }}">
   {{ $account->accountname}}
</a>
```

Original AccountController

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Account;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class AccountController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
    $this->middleware('auth');
    }



public function index()
    {
    $result = Auth::user()->account()->get();
    if(!$result->isEmpty()){
        return view('account.dashboard',['account'=>$result,'image'=>Auth::user()]);
    }
    else{
        return view('account.dashboard',['account'=>false,'image'=>Auth::user()]);
    }
}
```

Updated AccountController

```
public function index()
{          
$result = Auth::user()->account()->get();
    if(!$result->isEmpty()){
        return view(layouts.app,['account'=>$result,'image'=>Auth::user()]);
    }
    else{
        return view(layouts.app,['account'=>false,'image'=>Auth::user()]);
    }
}
```

Account.php

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Account extends Model
{
protected $table = 'accounts';

protected $fillable = ['id', 'accountname',  'address1', 'address2', 'city', 'state', 'zip', 'accountalpha', 'accountnotes'];

public function account()
    {
    return $this->hasMany('App\User');
    }
}
```

Routes

```
Route::get('/', function () {
return redirect('/login');
});

Auth::routes();

Route::resource('account','AccountController');

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');
```

'accounts' table

```
Schema::create('accounts', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id')->unsigned();
        $table->string('accountname');
        $table->string('accountalpha')->nullable();
        $table->string('address1');
        $table->string('address2');
        $table->string('city');
        $table->string('state');
        $table->integer('zip');
        $table->string('accountnotes')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

'users' table

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('firstname');
        $table->string('lastname');            
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->string('phonenumber');
        $table->string('password');
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->integer('account_id');

        $table->foreign('account_id')->references('id')->on('accounts')->onDelete('cascade');
```

Comment: you are sending the result to the dashboard.blade.php from the controller but you have the a tag in app.blade.php , so there is the problem, change the view name or change the dashboard to app in the controller

Comment: I updated the controller to point to the layouts.app view and I am getting the same undefined variable error.